# Why are Angular 2+ Router route definitions Javascript Objects instead of Typescript Classes?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-router

The default use of the Angular 2+ Router involves adding route definitions to the app-routing module.

### app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AboutComponent } from './pages/about/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

These are added as Javascript Objects in the form `{ path: '[path]', component: '[componentName]' }`. However, the stated best-practice is to define data outside of the component. (This [Angular.io tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#creating-a-class-for-the-data) provides a good example)

Is there a reason we don't see a "routeDefinition" typescript class? Something like this:

### route-definition.ts

```
 export class RouteDefinition {
    constructor(
        public path: string,
        public component: string) {}

    //Add additional constructors as needed
}
```

Then instead of

```
{ path: '[path]', component '[component]' }
```

you would implement it with

```
new Route ('[path]', '[component]')
```

If there is not a reason, would it be against best practice to create and use this class? (I know I can do whatever I would like to in my own projects, but I find it very useful to stick to best practices wherever they are defined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you are suggesting is already the same with the implementation. As you can see there is a [Routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes) type and it is an alias for Route[], whereas the [Route interface](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) contains all possible fields for a Route definition.